# Typescript: how to loop through an object indexed by enum values

Tags: typescript, for-loop, enums

I have an object declared like that:

```
type MyType = { [key in MyEnum]?: number}
```

MyEnum has that form:

```
enum MyEnum {
  Foo = 1, Bar = 2
}
```

I want to loop over my object key/value pairs, and get back to the enum value:

```
const myObject: MyType = {...}
for (const myKey in myObject) {
  // myKey is of type string, not "MyEnum". How to get back to it?
}
```

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Please make your code complete. Provide a definition for `MyEnum` and for `myObject`.

Comment: `MyType` comes out as `{ 0?: number;  1?: number;  2?: number }`. What you intended? It doesn't look like it.

Comment: I complete the exemple @spender

Answer (score 2):

This seemingly surprising issue is the consequence of duck typing in Typescript and to a lesser extent how objects work in Javascript.

The `myKey` is typed as a string, because of two reasons. Firstly, Typescript cannot guarantee that an object will only contain properties of `MyType`. Duck typing allows you to use objects that have the same and more properties as `MyType` on places where `MyType` is requested. This is a feature of Typescript, but in this case a handicap.

**Example of duck typing**

```
// Types
enum MyEnum {
  Foo = 1, Bar = 2
};

type MyType = { [key in MyEnum]?: number}

// Duck typing example
const normalObject: MyType = { [MyEnum.Foo]: 3, [MyEnum.Bar]: 4 };
const duckTypedObject = { [MyEnum.Foo]: 5, "extraProperty": 10};

function myFunction(obj: MyType){
  for (const myKey in obj) {
    console.log(myKey);
  }
}

myFunction(normalObject);
// This will print out "extraProperty" as well.
myFunction(duckTypedObject);
```

Second, because properties on objects in Javascript can only be symbols or strings other types are coerced into strings. Since the for loop will only iterate over the string properties of an object, Typescript chooses `string` as the most specific type for `myKey`.

Normally you could still type `myKey` by declaring a variable outside the `loop` construct. In this case that does not work, because you are using a numeric enum. You would need to parse the strings in order to get the numbers again and cast it back into an enum. I would highly advise against this. You could however use a
string enum, but this would still expose you to errors if your colleagues would use duck typing.

**String Enum Solution**

```
enum MyStringEnum {
  Foo = "FOO", Bar = "BAR"
}

type MyType2 = { [key in MyStringEnum]?: number};
const obj: MyType2 = { [MyStringEnum.Foo]: 3};

let myKey: MyStringEnum;
for (const myKey in obj){
  console.log(myKey);
}
```

My suggestion would be to use the `Map` type from Typescript. As you can see the key is typed without any additional hacks and you evade issues with regard to duck typing.

```
enum MyEnum {
  Foo = 1, Bar = 2
};

let myMap = new Map<MyEnum, number>([
  [MyEnum.Foo, 3],
  [MyEnum.Bar, 4]
]); 

for (const [key] of myMap){
  console.log(key);
}
```

[Here is a link to the executable code snippet.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=4&ssc=3&pln=2&pc=1#code/PTAEBEFcGMGtQCoE8AOBLAdgc1AUQB4CGAtigDYCmAUBRpMaALJK50MDeVooAYgPZ9QAXlABGADSgAQoQBOw0ACYqAXwDcVKgBdUFJkmQo9I9qADasCklCZ9regF0A-AC5QbAEYVZKzdD4YAM5a7nyyxIRkAPIeAFYU0FpuzIbGoKZmzPbEAHT8fA5uAMySmSxsOTKyhaAALKDqVP5BIQAmMLCprTHxiQoZWRX5NQCskgBEFPhasoQACrJ8RrI6426iAAyNVABmkBiJaAGgxEg8%204cBABR8cckGugCUnNw7YaBXzcEnSADSVjYMKBbrFHukuNxQF8%20JQcmQ%20Fgrqd-khHhpuL5fFRTucDlojhgrhgwhFonEElo0VQQIgABZoQKgADuaDIZFAKFkmBCfEgIUm01mCyW3lWoEIjKZFDZOWxZwu%20Ou7TgXR6FKp1LAAGUYXyCWJkoQUB8tTMAlgyNZORQdt5ZBRWo8qJQQqdGEaFBgKEymEaADyDeiSTzeAB8VzMELK2TyAkkRQc4ijgdyVUktQcVAcaNAmje8k%20AW%20FisDmBOx%207pQzwh0Nh8MRllRGixNJ1ZD1x0UblNXOweDYHykFG%20xJCWkEkECFCdtHo%20l7mCw2XB3HyCnGPCiUXGkiqG6kAEEAErjVSaHRGfSpRT9cxNwELmZL7LONwhnwaL48u7X3S3kxzGYRdsBjYZim2F0fhRe4QOXNgNHzD5v2ggFbBBGtuDrCg4QRJE-isKkVCAA)

Comment: Thanks! I am serializing and deserializing this objet in MongoDB and through network, so the Map type is not a viable option for me unfortunately.

Comment: @RomainF. Which library are you using to serialize it? I would then suggest to maybe look into a string enum if this is a possibility. Are there any specific reasons to use a numeric enum?

Comment: I am not using any library for serialization, only JSON parse and stringify (and MongoDB raw data on database side).
Because I use raw data on database side, using numeric enum saves space.
The project is here: https://game-park.com/. Each board game has a custom data structure, but can be adapted without worrying about the databases or data transfers. Awesome gain of time.

Answer (score 1):

```js
enum MyEnum {
  Foo = 1, Bar = 2
}

type MyType = { [key in MyEnum]?: number}


declare var myObject: MyType;

for (const myKey in myObject) {
  // myKey is of type string, not "MyEnum". How to get back to it?
}
```

This made by design. Please be aware that `Object.keys(MyEnum)` will also return `string[]` instead of `Array<keyof typeof MyEnum>`.

In order to do that, you need to use `type assertion` - `as` operator.

```js
enum MyEnum {
    Foo = 1, Bar = 2
}

type MyType = Record<keyof typeof MyEnum, 1>


declare var myObject: typeof MyEnum;


const loop =
    (Object.keys(MyEnum) as Array<keyof typeof MyEnum>)
        .forEach(elem => { // elem is Foo | Bar

        })
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAsgngUXNA3gKCpqAxA9rqAXigEYAaKAIQEMAnIqAJjQF800AXOAB2FjgAqPPsQBKwAMa5aAEwA8Aa2BxcAMyhdea-kkgUSAPnZoZkgDZ0%20ANzpQIcAPIAjAFaSOALg3Dt8XRABuYykQAGcOKDN8biIMLAAKZzcJDgA6JThQ%20L9kAEooalCoAEFaWmo4RWVtTWBfRGQDXLisLFTVaQRqCQALeOAzYGhCAygUKAB6CagBoagASyK8AgAfKjp2VtaWZqA)

**UPDATE**

```js
enum MyEnum {
    Foo = 1, Bar = 2
}

type MyType = Record<keyof typeof MyEnum, 1>


declare var myObject: typeof MyEnum;

type Values<T> = T[keyof T]
type O = {
    [Prop in Values<typeof MyEnum>]: Prop
}

const loop =
    (Object.values(MyEnum) as Array<Values<typeof MyEnum>>)
        .forEach((elem /** 1 | 2 */) => { })
```

Comment: For me with your example, elem is "Foo" | "Bar", the enum keys as strings, not the enum values.
I am trying to use "parseInt" right now, as my enum values are integers only.

Comment: You seem to be looping over the keys of the enum itself, rather than an object whose keys are typed by the enum.