# Typescript enum index object iterate over object

Tags: typescript, enums

I have the following enum

```
enum FunnelStage {
    LOGIN
}
```

then I have the following object

```
const overall = {
    [FunnelStage.LOGIN]: {count: 1}
}
overall[FunnelStage.Login].count = 2
```

and later I want to iterate over the `overall` object like so

```
for (let funnelStage in overall) {
    console.log(overall[funnelStage].count)
}
```

this gives me an error - `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Record<FunnalStage, { count: number; }>'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Record<FunnalStage, { count: number; }>'`

How do I achieve my loop ?

I tried also like this but it gives me the same error

```
for (let funnelStageKey in Object.keys(overall) as Array<keyof typeof FunnalStage>) {
    const count = overall[funnelStageKey].count;
    console.log(count);
}
```

[LINK TO PLAYGROUND](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAYmIgIYBsDKAXRBzYUDeAUFMVADIDyA4gJIByBAvgQQMYD2IAzulGwG7AATimQAuKACVg7QQBMAPHAQoM2YABp87eOnHgIAIyEMAfFAC8%20IiQDaSpGkw4AdBRq0AuuLzaQuqACMTAxQzOxcbMjAzshsWAAU-EIiNgAMHs6%206ACUzABmbIJQ8VE8efAgwI5qUACWILwCwsjI2VYkUOGckdGxCUnNyDblCFWqOBlZuUwEBUUlwGUVY07AANLAAJ51DeQGAFbS6M4A1luciU0ibYicUACCgsKb8mebbHlQ6JsADsAfsAqKlWJjahA6XR4WQsjWSLWGy2qOA2m0mbB0AG5rMQuj0YnF4lMsQwgA)

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68597003/typescript-how-to-loop-through-an-object-indexed-by-enum-values

Comment: I looked at this and tried it but was not able to run it. If you understand it - please create an answer with code related to my user case, so that I can understand it and I will mark it as correct